# How can I replicate multiple primary constructors?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I'm not sure what Kotlin best practice is in this area.

Say I have a Java class, `User` that has two fields: `username` and `password`. It has a primary constructor like this:

```
public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = hashPassword(password);
}
```

and a second constructor for the ORM:

```
public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

(plus lots more fields not shown)

With this setup, I can present a friendly face to most of the code, and still let the ORM pass all the fields in to recreate the object from the database.

My Kotlin code has a primary constructor as such:

```
class User(var username: String,
       var name: String,
       password: String)
```

with an initializer that calls `hashPassword` and assigns it to a private property.

How can I construct a secondary constructor properly, such that I don't have to hash the value coming out of the database?

Comment: Both of these constructors have the same signature? This wouldn't work in Java either

Comment: @Mango No, they have different signatures, I'm just boiling it down for that example.

Comment: @JasonB pls down boil it down to a point where it is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

> (plus lots more fields not shown)

By assuming that this means you second constructor has a different signature, e.g. by adding another field to its parameter list, what you want can be achieved several ways:

1. Create a private primary constructor and several secondary constructors:

   ```
   class User
   private constructor(val username : String)
   {
       private val password : String

       constructor(username : String, password : String)
           : this(username)
       {
           this.password = hashPassword(password)
       }

       constructor(username : String, password : String, anotherParameter : String)
           : this(username)
       {
           this.password = password
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make `password` a `var` and assign the password again after calling the primary constructor (Please note that this requires **Kotlin 1.2** or later):

   ```
   class User(val username : String, password : String)
   {
       private lateinit var password : String

       init
       {
           if (!this::password.isInitialized)
               this.password = hashPassword(password)
       }

       constructor(username : String, password : String, anotherParameter : String)
           : this(username, password)
       {
           this.password = password
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a flag to the primary constructor that tells whether the password was already hashed

   ```
   class User(val username : String, password : String, isHashed : Boolean = false)
   {
       private val password : String

       init
       {
           this.password = if (isHashed) password else hashPassword(password)
       }

       constructor(username : String, password : String, anotherParameter : String)
           : this(username, password, isHashed=true)
   }
   ```

Comment: I was trying to come up with implementation #1. I think first two are the best way to do it.

Comment: @Clinkz Although the third one is the shortest solution I'd probably prefer the first, but depending on the use case the it might not be always the best one

Comment: Thanks for that example, I hadn't considered a private constructor like that. What I've done for now is have the primary constructor define all fields as they should be, and create a factory method in the companion object to handle the hashing and what not. I'll continue playing around with various options.